# Null Pointer Exception When Trying To Access ActionBar

Tags: java, android

I am currently trying to add a custom layout to my action bar but keep running into a null pointer exception and can't figure out a way around it.

Here is my onCreateOptionsMenu

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
    TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.menuText);
    mTitleTextView.setText("Insert Title Here");

    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.menuPlusButton);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start New Course", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

The error seems to occur at mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false) which indicates that `ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar()` is returning null, and I cant figure out why. I extend AppCompatActivity and am running min API 7.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `getActionBar()` with `getSupportActionBar()` and change your imports to match.